# Passing a 'Payload' to an AWS Lambda function with the AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use the aws php sdk to invoke a aws-lambda function and get the return value like so:

```
    $client = LambdaClient::factory([
        'key' => 'mykey',
        'secret' => 'mysecret',
        'region' => 'us-west-2'
    ]);

    $payload = [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3'
    ];

    $result = $client->invoke([
        'FunctionName' => 'testFunction',
        'Payload' => json_encode($payload)
    ]);
```

For some reason i'm getting an ErrorException in StatusCodeVisitor.php on line 21. "Illegal string offset 'StatusCode'"

When I don't include the

```
'Payload' => json_encode($payload)
```

Then I don't get an error, but I also don't pass any data into my lambda function which defeats the purpose.

Can anyone see anything I could be doing wrong? This seems like a trivial example.

Edit - Adding link to documentation on This function

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Lambda.LambdaClient.html#_invoke

Comment: show the contents of `$payload`

Comment: I am already, I create $payload just a couples lines above where I use it

Comment: Its all good haha, you had me worried for a sec :)

Comment: statsuCode is the response ... can you dump the whole return

Comment: No it throws an exception. If I catch the exception and dump it, the exception message is "illegal string offset 'StatusCode'"

Comment: sounds like it fails before even getting a return, hence the lack of any statusCode - if that makes sense.

Comment: Yup, we're on the same page. I'm trying to figure out why its not returning. I must have something misconfigured but I need some help tracking down what it is.

Comment: Can you have a Look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451925/cannot-get-aws-lambda-function-response-in-php-client). Hoping you'd be able to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue and for some weird reason AWS SDK did not recognize the associate array in PHP. Maybe because at the time of JSON encoding associative array in PHP becomes object and SDK expect it as Array.

Changing `$payload` as follows will fix this issue.

```
$payload = array('test1', 'test3', 'test3');
```

Also remember that if you made changes in `$payload` you need to access them in the Lambda function as follows:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('value1 =', event[0]);
    console.log('value2 =', event[1]);
    console.log('value3 =', event[2]);
    context.succeed(event);  // Echo back the first key value
    // context.fail('Something went wrong');
};
```

**Update**

You can pass information like this:

```
$payload = array(
                "key1" => array(),
                "key2" => array()
            );
```